# impossible to start the onStartJob method

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler

I have the following code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.bluejob;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.job.JobInfo;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void scheduleJob(View v) {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, BlueJobM.class);
        JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(821, componentName)
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)
                .build();


        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        int resultCode;
         resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
        if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed");
        }
    }

    public void cancelJob(View v) {
        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        scheduler.cancel(821);
        Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled");
    }
}
```

**OnStartJob method in BlueJobM.java**

```
@Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job started");
        doBackgroundWork(params);

        return true;
    }
```

When I start the code on my Redmi I revive di series of errors:

```
2021-09-22 15:33:56.527 21306-21306/com.example.bluejob E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bluejob, PID: 21306
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{com.example.bluejob/com.example.bluejob.BlueJobM}
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1957)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871)
        at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule(IJobScheduler.java:184)
        at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:44)


       "I THINK THE ERROR IS HERE" at com.example.bluejob.MainActivity.scheduleJob(MainActivity.java:32)


        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService$JobSchedulerStub.enforceValidJobRequest(JobSchedulerService.java:2538)
        at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService$JobSchedulerStub.schedule(JobSchedulerService.java:2600)
        at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub.onTransact(IJobScheduler.java:60)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:735)
```

When I start the App I can enter in the CancelJob method which correctly calls onStopJob on **BlueJobM.java** (i can see the log).
When I remove this part of code form **MainActivity.java**

```
       int resultCode;
        resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
       if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled");
       } else {
           Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed");
       }
```

the error does not show up but the job doesn't start anyway.
I suspect the program has some problem building the Job but I'm not sure.

I put more code on Github if is needed https://github.com/jaxis/BlueJob.

I was following this tutorial soo the code should be similar to this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EQWmME-hNA&t .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan
 i have to add in the manifest under the <service> 
'android:name=".BlueJobM" ' or something else ?
I have tried this one and it does not work, I admit that I don't completely understand this part of the code Xp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service
> ComponentInfo{com.example.bluejob/com.example.bluejob.BlueJobM}

That means it doesn't know anything about that class as a component.  Generally this means you didn't add it to the manifest.  Every Service and Activity you want to use needs to be in the manifest.  In some cases BroadcastReceivers do as well (although not all).